# What is wrong with this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql

I cannot get this statement running on MySQL server:

```
DECLARE @tabl varchar(40)
SET @tabl = :uId;
SET @location = CONCAT('data_',@tabl);
SET @b = 'INSERT INTO' + @location + '(Id, uId , name , address, phone)
VALUES (:Id, :uId, :name, :address)';
Prepare stmt FROM @b;
Execute stmt;
```

I get this error:

> No value specified for parameter 1 - SQLException

Bindings will be done in another function.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Yes for missing space but still fail, what is wrong with CONCAT(), can you elaborate ?

Comment: if I want to use direct query not prepared can I do like this `INSERT INTO @location  (Id, uId , name , address, phone)
VALUES (:Id, :uId, :name, :address);`

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what you mean by

> Bindings will be done in another function.

You have an EXECUTE statement that is going to invoke your query right there and then, and that statement is not providing parameter values for your `:name` parameters. That is what the error message is about.

Your EXECUTE statement must have a USING clause, [as per the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execute.html):

```
EXECUTE stmt
USING @Id, @uId, @name, @address;
```

where *@Id*, *@uId*, *@name*, *@address* would probably be the names of arguments of the stored program containing the script in your question.

And then you will also need to address the issues mentioned by [Julien Vavasseur](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/72048/julien-vavasseur) and [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%e1%b5%80%e1%b4%b9):

- revisit the number of values vs the number of columns in the INSERT statement (and correct the USING clause above if necessary);
- make sure your INSERT statement is syntactically correct (no missing spaces between its various tokens where required).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to insert 4 values in 5 columns:

```
:Id      => Id  
:uId     => uId  
:name    => name  
:address => address  
???      => phone
```

You can either add or remove Phone

#### Add Phone:

```
INSERT INTO tableX(Id, uId, name, address, phone)
    VALUES (:Id, :uId, :name, :address, :phone)
```

#### If Phone allows NULL and you don't know its value (yet), it can also be removed:

```
INSERT INTO tableX(Id, uId , name , address)
    VALUES (:Id, :uId, :name, :address)
```

Comment: Thank you Julien , but that was a typo