# Dynamic table name in Insert query

Tags: mysql, table

I have asked a question about dynamic table name in a prepared statement [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142020/what-is-wrong-with-this-sql-statement) , but I want to know if Mysql server support dynamic table name like this :

```
SET @tbl = 'Dawin';

INSERT INTO @tbl (col1,col2) VALUES (val1,val2);
```

I think it doesn't support that , because I tried all that possible syntax that I know .

Comment: MySQL Does Not Support This. Please refer to your first question and the answer from Andriy (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/142024/877)

Comment: it does support  , Look [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38004200/6506661)

Comment: It does not support the syntax in your question. That's what I meant. I use prepared statements in many of my answers over the years : http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a877%20DEALLOCATE%20PREPARE